# Add image to button in unity

Tags: unity

Sorry if this question has already an answer somewhere, but I've just started to play with Unity and now I'm stuck. :(

I've tried a few things ( from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1127944/changing-the-image-of-a-button-with-a-script.html) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273435/unity-5-0-how-can-change-unity-ui-button-image) and [here](https://blog.gamedev.tv/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-the-ui-canvas-of-your-unity-game/) and others ) but none of them work, I'm sure that I do something wrong but I don't know what.

I have this code:

```
public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image myButtonImage; 
    private Button switchBtn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        switchBtn = GameObject.Find("switchBtn").GetComponent<Button>();
        myButtonImage = Resources.Load<Image>("switchCameraImg");

        switchBtn.image = myButtonImage;
    }
}
```

and this are my objects:

[image]

where `cameraSwitchObj` is a `GameObject` and `switchBtn` is the button itself.

`SceneManager` is the script attached to `MainCamera`

I receive this error :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object SceneManager.Start ()
```

for this line : `switchBtn.image = myButtonImage;` but according to what i read from different posts this is all i must do. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show what is switchCameraImg in your assets folder.
Also is this asset in your "Resources" directory?

Afaik, you cannot load Image via Resources.Load method. 
But you can load a Sprite, and next set a sprite of Image as loaded component.

Try this:

```
myButtonImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("someGraphics");
```

Where the sprite is an graphics, for example in ".png" extension, with Texture Type option set as "Sprite (2D and UI)":

[image]

Comment: Hmm, indeed, switchCameraImg is png, under Resources folder. So I must make a sprite with that image and then attach to object..

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 2017.2, Button already supports an images through the `Target Graphic` field.

Typically this is a 9-Patch image, but it's easy to turn an image into a 9-patch.

See the documentation for [Button](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Button.html).